How do I capitalize the field name of lombok setter & getter?
I have a field I want getters & setters for. The problem is that the field should be capitalized if it is occuring after the position in any field or method.
ex:
What I get
private final String url;

// auto - lombok
public String getUrl() {...};
public void setUrl(String url) {...};

What I want
private final String url;

// auto - lombok
public String getURL() {...};
public void setURL(String url) {...};

As additional context, the class is decorated with @Data and there are only few fields I need this behaviour for.

No it should not be capitalized. Follow the Java Naming Conventions.

Lombok only modifies the capitalization of the first letter:

For generating the method names, the first character of the field, if it is a lowercase character, is title-cased, otherwise, it is left unmodified. Then, get/set/is is prefixed.

So you could technically rename your field to URL, but it'd violate the ALL_CAPS static final variable name convention.

Or you can just make a getter yourself and disable the auto-generated getter, assuming you're using something like @Data:
@Getter(AccessLevel.NONE)
private final String url;

public String getURL() {
    return url;
}


Thanks for this, we've decided to stick with Lombok defaults, and use Url like casing for abbreviations
